# How do you configure a TACACS+ tac_plus server on Ubuntu 16.04 that authenticates against Microsoft Active Directory?

Tags: ldap, active-directory

How do you configure a TACACS+ tac_plus server on Ubuntu 16.04 that authenticates against Microsoft Active Directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've moved the guide to https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/45436/how-do-you-configure-a-tacacs-tac-plus-server-on-ubuntu-16-04-that-authenticate so I only have to maintain it in one location.